# Testing divisibility of Integer by 13 and 7

Tags: math, haskell, division

Problem- max number which is divisible by 13 and 7 between 0-100.

i am trying to write a code in Haskell for checking divisibility for 13 and 7. I am able to write for 13 but not able to check for 7 in the same code.

```
lard :: (Integral a) => a  
lard = head ( filter p[100,99..]) 
    where p x   = x `mod` 13 == 0
```

Comment: well, `filter p` produces all numbers that are divisible by 13. Now out of those, filter out all numbers that are divisible by 7. Clearly, composing filters `filter ((==0).(``mod``7)) . filter ((==0).(``mod``13))` is the same as composing the predicates with `&&`, like suggested below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `&&` to check for both conditions. The overall evaluation is true only if both the operands are true. This operator exists for many (C-like) languages

Like:

```
lard :: (Integral a) => a  
lard = head ( filter p[100,99..]) 
    where p x   = (x `mod` 13 == 0) && (x `mod` 7 == 0)
```

<sup>Warning: There might be better ways of doing this. I just stepped into the world of Haskell. :)</sup>

Comment: Thank you.I am also new to world of Haskell. Was trying this way but was not able to get.thanks lot

Comment: `[100,99,..]` doesn't stop at 0, so if you were checking for ```head ( filter p [100,99..]) where p x   = (x `mod` 13 == 0) && (x `mod` 21 == 1)``` you'd get -104.  *But* this is secretly a good thing.  If you did use `[100,99..1]` you'd get an exception.  A good compromise might be using `listToMaybe` instead of `head` and having `lard :: (Integral a) => Maybe a` so you can only look between 1 and 100 but fail safely.

Comment: @rampion, `listToMaybe . filter p` is the definition of `find`.

Comment: Didn't know about [`Data.List.find`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v:find), thanks!

Answer (score -1):

`module Division where
 divisibility :: [Int] -> [String]
 divisibility (x:xs) = map show([if x`mod`13 == 0 && x`mod`7 == 0 then "divideby13and7"
 else if x`mod`13 == 0 then "divideby13"
 else if x`mod`7 == 0 then "divideby7" else show(x)| x<-x:xs]`

Comment: This does not actually answer the question. Please re-read the question and read the existing answer before deciding whether you have something new to contribute (in which case you should edit your answer) or not, in which case you should delete your answer.

Comment: The question asked is about a haskell program to check divisibility of 13 and 7 at same time right for any number of list and just not only 1 to 100. Have you tried atleast this program and see before commenting..